# Lambda factor copyable or moveable

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, copy-constructor, move-constructor

A lambda is just an instance of a nameless class. If it doesn't capture anything, it won't even have any member variables.

I think whether a specific lambda is copyable or moveable lies on whether the actually captured objects(and variables) are copyable or moveable.

Furthermore, if a specific lambda captures all the objects(or call them as variables) as **reference**, then this lambda factor **must** be moveable and copyable.

But this [code snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/n3fz7TGo3) makes me totally confused(please pay attention to the comment in the code snippet):

```
#include <mutex>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

constexpr int FOO_NUM = 5;

int main()
{
    std::mutex mt_lk;
    
    auto factor1 =[&mt_lk](){{
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mt_lk);
        std::cout << "hello world, first" << std::endl;
    }};
    
    auto factor2 = factor1;
    
    auto factor3 = std::move(factor1); //I think the mt_lk is already moved here.
    
    factor2();
    factor3();
    
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mt_lk); //I think mt_lk could not be called here. But no problem is found now.
    std::cout << "hello world, second" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: @273K Could you please explain that in more detail for me?

Comment: `std::mutex` is neither movable nor copyable, all `factor*` get references to `mt_lk`.

Comment: @273K If I understand you correctly, `std::move(factor1)` moves the reference of `mt_lk` other than the referenced object itself(i.e `ml_lk`). Am I right?

Comment: @273K `factor*` only has a reference to `mt_lk`. So it's both movable and copyable here. But they will give the same result in this case. Just as copying and moving an `int` is the same thing.